# GIM mechanism and $K_L$ decay

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction

I'm trying to solve the problem (14.5) of *Introduction to Nuclear and Particle physics*  by *A. Das* and *T. Ferbel*.

What am I trying to do is to prove that $\langle Z^0|d\bar{s}\rangle = 0$ by introducing the weak mixing state $(d',s')$.

The solution says that $\langle Z^0|d\bar{s}\rangle = 0$ can be expressed as
$$\langle Z^0|d\bar{s}\rangle = \langle Z^0 | d'\bar{d}'\rangle\cos\theta
_c \sin\theta_c + \langle Z^0 | d' \bar{s}'\rangle\cos^2\theta_c - \langle Z^0 | s' \bar{d}'\rangle\sin^2\theta_c - \langle Z^0 | s'\bar{s}'\rangle \sin\theta_c \cos\theta_c ~, $$
where $\theta_c$ is the Cabbibo angle. That's fine and obvious.  Moreover, the solution says that the brackets involving different flavors vanish because of the *orthogonality of weak eigenstates*.

This is where I get confused. I think that the composite quark state ($d'\bar{s}'$, for example,) is mathematically identical to
$$d' \otimes \bar{s}'.$$

And this has nothing to do with any orthogonality. Am I  wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. One takes the trace of the tensor product.

The primed "weak eigenstate" basis actually *means*
$$
 \langle Z^0 | d' \bar{s}'\rangle=  \langle Z^0 s'| d'  \rangle\ \propto  \langle  s'| d'  \rangle\  =0.
$$

The states in *both* the unprimed and the primed basis are orthonormal, of course,  but
*only* in the prime basis the $Z^0$ couples diagonally: no flavor-changing neutral current in the definition of the SM.